# How to get the name of the parent folder from a file path?

Tags: vba, path, directory

Using VBA, is it possible to get the name of the folder that contains a file?

Input: `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`

Output: `System32`

Comment: `StrReverse(Split(StrReverse("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"), "\")(1))`

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's close but it returns the full parent path

Answer (score 2):

This will return the parent folder name:

```
Public Function GetParentFolderName(ByVal path As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    With fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        result = .GetParentFolderName(path)
        GetParentFolderName = Mid(result, InStrRev(result, "\") + 1)
    End With
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Sub GetParentFolderNameTest()
    Debug.Print GetParentFolderName("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")
End Sub
```

Output:

```
System32
```

Comment: @Fidel ...You can write in Documentation section to Improve the skills.Instead of asking question and giving answer to that.. Thanks.

Comment: @HA560 I don't think that deserves a topic (or a Q&A) on its own... `GetParentFolderName` is already documented, as is `InStrRev` - this is really nothing but combining the two.

Comment: The grand majority of solutions on SO are a combination of simple bits of code. The reason I posted Q&A was because I didn't find a solution to this problem on SO or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can do simpler (no ref needed ):

```
Function ParentFolder(ByVal path As String)
        vArray = Split(path, "\")
        size = UBound(vArray)
        ParentFolder= vArray(size - 1)
End Function
```

Then call

```
ParentFolder( "what\ever\path\to\a\file.ext" )
```

If you need the parent folder of a folder like, replace the last line by

```
ParentFolder = vArray(size)
```

for example, the parent folder of the current application (excel workbook)

```
ParentFolder( ActiveWorkbook.path )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I wrote to answer a very similar problem, when this post didn't have a satisfactory answer for me.

```
Function parentFolderName(ByVal path As String)
Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    parentFolderName = Dir(fso.GetParentFolderName(path), vbDirectory)
End Function
```

calling the function as so:

```
Debug.Print parentFolderName("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")
```

This will print "System32", and if the directory does not exist it returns an empty String "". This will work whether the path is to a file or a folder/directory, as the Dir function "Returns a String representing the name of a file, directory, or folder that matches a specified pattern or file attribute, or the volume label of a drive" (from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function)

I feel this is a little simpler than all of the string manipulation that could easily introduce errors.